# Translation and a rotation of the magnetic field of a line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, definite-integrals, electromagnetism

I need to solve the magnetic field created by a wire with an arc shape. This integral is very complicated, so I decided to approximate the arc into circular chords and calculate the magnetic field of these small segments. The integral to solve looks like $$\int \frac{dy'}{[z^2+(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2]^{3/2}}$$  and considering that the segments have a general orientation
$$ y'=px'+b $$

This integral is difficult for Mathematica, so it gives me a conditional expression with a lot of assumptions, which I believe is wrong because it doesn't match my numerical result. My new idea is to calculate the magnetic field of a vertical segment perpendicular to the, let's say, x axis, so the integral would be easier to solve:

$$\int \frac{dy'}{[z^2+(x-x_0)^2+(y-y')^2]^{3/2}}$$

I want to use the result of this integral to, by translations and rotations, calculate the magnetic field of the different circular chords. How could you make this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\oint_S B\cdot dr = \mu_0 I_{encl}$ and you can parameterize the integral by taking a circular path of arbitrary radius.

Comment: I don't have a closed path. The sources of the magnetic field are circular sections originally, and straight finite segments in my approximation. Also, I can't integrate any magnetic field if I don't know it. I think this would be useful if I knew a region where the magnetic field is going to be constant.

Comment: @Psyphy you don't need to integrate the field.

Comment: Then I think I don't get your idea. I know the current but I don't know how the magnetic field is inside that path that I choose. Actually, I have no idea at all of how the magnetic field is going to be.

Comment: @Psyphy try some geometric inspection. The field is at most a Function of  $r, \phi, z$. Put a test point at some spot -- the source looks the same if I move it only in z or the angle. So it must be a function of r only. Yet if I take the path at constant radius, dr is not a function of r.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make myself clear. You are talking about the typical problem solved using Ampere's law. Maybe I should change the word "circular section" for "arc". Then, the symmetry you are talking about is not valid in this case. Hence my problem to solve the integral.

Comment: Yes. I believe I misunderstood...you mean a hoop shape?

Comment: I understand a hoop shape as a circumference of $2\pi$ rad. My problem is a piece of that hoop. Therefore, my source of magnetic field is an arc of $\theta<\pi$ rad. Less than the half of a hoop

Comment: @Psyphy if it isn't a closed or infinite surface than how can it physically sustain a current?